# How to use token to perform actions from 2 different youtube profiles

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I would like to upload a video to YouTube using the `Profile A` and should be able to add it to playlist of `Profile B`.
I tried using the YouTube API V3 and I am able to:

1. Upload the video
2. Add the video to a playlist

When I was trying to do it in a unique sequence the profile used is that one of the step 1 and I receive an error message as the playlist is owned by a different profile.

Comment: Can you share the error message you have encountered?

Comment: Can you show us your code? What did you try?